# Python data detector for changing numbers to 0 and 1: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, indexing

I have written some codes as below.

```
a = [3, 2, 3, 4, 50, 60, 3, 70, 60, 4, 2, 3]

def interval(data):
    threshold = 50
    n = [0 for i in a]
    for i in data:
        if data[i] < threshold and data[i+1] < threshold and data[i+2] < threshold :
            n[i] = 1
            n[i+2] = 1
    return n

print (interval(a))

## IndexError: list index out of range
```

As you can see above, I have a list(a) containing some data and also a threshold, which is 50. Each element in the list (a) corresponds to 1 second. The data is wave-shaped and there is a peak in this data set. What I want to do is to detect the duration of the wave, which is from 5(sec) to 8(sec). One thing to be noticed is that some data in the peak will be lower than the threshold, but only for a small of time. So it should be ignored and still be considered inside the peak.

Thus, the first thing I am going to do is to have those data in the peak to be 0, and the rest (interval) to be 1. So I make a new list(n) inside the function and try to have those 0 and 1 in the new list (n). So the final list(n) should be [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]. However, when I run the code above, it gives an error "IndexError: list index out of range".

If anyone knows how to solve this, please let me know. Appreciated!!

Comment: `i in data` does **not generate indices**, it **iterates over the elements**, so `i` will first take `3` as value... You can replace it with `for i in range(len(data)-2)`.

Comment: Thank you a lot!! pls see my update of the question above. I tried the range function and it kinda worked. But this time it returns the list (n) to be [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], which is not as expected. Could you pls take a look and see where is wrong with the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a *list comprehension*:

```
>>> [int(x<50) for x in a]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I didn't use list comprehension is because that I have a bigger data set and if I plot the data it is like a wave shaped. So I want to detect some intervals between the wave. However, the peak of the wave is not always larger that the threshold (it might get lower for a small amount of time). So I want to write a detector to detect those intervals and make them to 1, and the wave part to be 0. Pls let me know if there's any way to solve it thanks!

Comment: What you're trying to do is now unclear, now that you edited your question.

Comment: I have updated my description of the question. It should be more clearer now. Please check my edit above. Thanks!!